# How to give warning or display message when notification already running of same application

Tags: android, notifications

Currently when I press the start stopwatch icon,notification is started and application is closed.If after five minute again I open the application and press on start stopwatch icon it should display some message that notification already running do you want to reset.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
String MyText = "Reminder";
Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
//The three parameters are: 1. an icon, 2. a title, 3. time when the notification appears

String MyNotificationTitle = "Practice Time!";
String MyNotificationText  = "";
MyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Log_Practice_timeActivity.class);
MyIntent.putExtra("s11", "Timer");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
MyIntent.putExtra("s1",cal.getTimeInMillis());
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date1 = new Date();
MyIntent.putExtra("startTime",dateFormat1.format(date1));

DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date2 = new Date();
MyIntent.putExtra("startDate",dateFormat2.format(date2));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int)(Math.random() * 100),MyIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//A PendingIntent will be fired when the notification is clicked. The FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag cancels the pendingintent

mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText,pendingIntent);
mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0,   mNotification);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) run the timer in the background and use a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to keep track of the progress. Whenever the user enters your application only then will you be able to do this. You can refer to [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) and also [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering..I just wanted to check notifcation is running already if display toast only..i dont want to make compltecated

Comment: ok then, but do try to implement these afterwards.

Comment: ya..if unable to do this way.then i definately use service..thanx man